# mysql calculate percentage in select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, percentage

I have a basic voting system that collects votes. Tabulation should take total yes votes divided by total votes to determine if a 2/3rd majority is reached.
Currently, I can return the data using this query

```
select sum(case when vote is not null and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) 
as total_votes, 
sum(case when vote=1 and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_yes from votes;
```

this returns

```
+-------------+-----------+
| total_votes | total_yes |
+-------------+-----------+
|           3 |         2 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

what I would like to do is something like this

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| total_votes | total_yes | YESPercent|
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|           3 |         2 |      66.6 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried by using something like this:

```
select sum(case when vote is not null and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_votes, 
sum(case when vote=1 and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_yes,
sum(total_votes,total_yes,(total_yes/total_votes)*100) as YESPercent from votes;
```

It doesn't recognize the total_yes or total_votes for the final portion.. Any tips or links to good guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neatest way to do this, IMHO, would be to have the basic results in a subquery and calculate using them in the outer query. Note that since you're only interested in `recruit_id = 49631` in both columns, this condition can be moved to the `where` clause. It will also, probably, slightly improve the query's performance. As another improvement, you could use the more straight forward `count` instead `sum` by using its quality of skipping `null`s:

```
SELECT total_votes, total_yes, total_yes * 100 / total_votes AS yes_percent
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(vote) AS total_votes, 
               COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 1 THEN 1 END) as total_yes,
         FROM  votes
         WHERE recruit_id = 49631) t
```

Comment: pasting this directly in results in `'FROM  votes WHERE recruit_id = 49631) t'` I modified it to have as t; as the end with the same result. I'm still playing with the code a little trying to figure out what's up. thank you for the tip on ignoring nulls by using count, it definitely sped my query time up!

Comment: i got it working by doing this, i need to add some more data to the table to ensure it's working as expected, but thank you! `select sum(total_yes*100/total_votes) as Yes_Percent from (select count(vote) as total_votes,count(case when vote=1 then 1 end) as total_yes from votes where recruit_id=49631) as t;`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to make your original query a subquery to accomplish this:

```
SELECT total_votes, total_yes, sum(total_votes,total_yes,(total_yes/total_votes)*100) as YESPercent
FROM
(select 
sum(case when vote is not null and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_votes, 
sum(case when vote=1 and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_yes
from votes) as v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly depending on the SQL dialect, aliases can be re-used or not. In mysql you are limited on this. The solution is a subquery:

```
SELECT total_votes,total_yes,sum(total_votes,total_yes,
(total_yes/total_votes)*100) as YESPercent 
FROM (
  select sum(case when vote is not null and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_votes, 
  sum(case when vote=1 and recruit_id=49631 then 1 else 0 end) as total_yes,
  sum(total_votes,total_yes,(total_yes/total_votes)*100) as YESPercent
  from votes) a;
```